# Using an if/else statement to return a boolean

Tags: java, oop, if-statement, boolean

I have a method that takes an array as a parameter and returns a boolean.

Inside the method, I have an if/else statement. If the statement is true, I want the result to return true, if the statement is false, I want the statement to returns false.

```
public static boolean allPositive (double[] arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return //What do i put here?
}
```

}

Of course, it needs a return value at the end. However, I am confused on what I should return at the bottom. How should I rewrite this?

Comment: Why you method called `allPositive` if you check onli first element?

Comment: @talex what do you mean? he's going through the whole array?

Comment: @DreadHeadedDeveloper No. Look at it closer : the code will end at the first iteration with either `return true` or `return false`

Comment: I stand corrected, thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, your code is wrong. For example, with `{1, -1, 2}`, your method will return true.

If you write it differently, you avoid the problem :

```
public static boolean allPositive (double[] arr) {
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i] < 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

**EDIT** : Or even better, a one-line solution with Java 8 and Streams (I like one-line solutions):

```
public static boolean allPositive (double[] arr) {
  //Stream the array and see if any elements matches condition `<0`.
  return !Arrays.stream(arr).anyMatch(i->i<0);
}
```

If you need more than one line of code in order to work with collections, then you should learn about [Streams](http://download.java.net/lambda/b78/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html).

Answer (score 3):

```
public static boolean allPositive (double[] arr)
{

    boolean b = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        if(!(arr[i] > 0))
        {
            b = false;
        }

    }
    return b;
}
```

The way Java works, it ensures no problems with your code by making sure all your returns happen outside of the if else statement. This because, a common bug by programmers is to return in the if else statement, but never create an else condition, so the method never returns anything. Doing it this way is more of a good practice thing so you don't bug out later trying to figure out why a method won't return.

Comment: This actually checks *if the last element is positive*. You should change `b = true` to `b = b && true`, and initialize `b` to `true` at the beginning.

Comment: How about this? It's different than how you put it but I think it solves the problem

Comment: seems good. It only depends on the definition of "positive" (in France, it means `>= 0`, whereas in the US, it means `>0`) but the algorithm is good.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle ??????? wait what? What do you mean? I am American so I have never heard of this before

Comment: @DreadHeadedDeveloper It is a matter of convention. For us (frenchs) `positive` means `>=0` and `strictly positive` means `>0`. Whereas it seems that in the US `>=0` is called `non negative` and `>0` is simply called `positive`. Can you confirm?

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle I can, I'm just surprised I have never heard of this before... Does this have to do with Locale?

Comment: @DreadHeadedDeveloper No, the program will not behave differently. I was just wondering what the method called `allPositive` should return (depending on how the developer interprets `positive`)

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Well I very much appreciate that, never heard of this before... I will keep that in mind when I head over to Nice next year!

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Arnaud has multiple return statements. Code smell.  The answer by DreadHeadedDeveloper has a logic error if the array is {1,-1,2}, it returns true.

This function/method is terse and follows good coding practices.

```
public static boolean allPositive (double[] arr) {
    boolean ret = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i] <= 0) {
            ret = false;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain my error? In fact, yours is almost exactly like mine!!

Comment: Now you have me confused, what could I have done wrong, I really don't see where my error is!!

Comment: Why does my code smell? I think that it is a good thing that the loop stops at the first negative number. Would you prefer a `break`maybe? Multiple return statements are bad in C but I don't think that they are bad in Java.

Comment: Sorry DreadHeadedDeveloper, after looking, it's correct. the negative (!) threw me for a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return in the end of the method (after the loop) the value that should be returned if an empty array is passed to your method. It's up to you to decide whether an empty array is "allPositive" or not.